# Vim imaps stopped working on Mac?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I was using an older version of vim on Windows, then I switched to a Mac computer and MacVim and brought over my imap files and vimrc, but the imaps no longer work. When I open a file it gives me an "Error detected while processing .. etc. ftplugins/html_imaps.vim" for example:

line    1:

```
E15: Invalid expression: ";"^M
```

The line in question in the imap file says:

```
let maplocalleader=";"
```

Is there a reason this doesn't work anymore? It was also giving me an error on each empty line. I deleted the empty lines so those errors went away, but I haven't been able to do anything about maplocalleader line.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is the semicolon supposed to be outside the quotes or is one missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `.vimrc` file came from a Windows machine, it has `\r\n` line endings, so you need to get rid of the `\r` (which shows up as `^M`). It looks like my Mac doesn't have `dos2unix`, so you'll probably want to just use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' <~/.vimrc >tmp
mv tmp ~/.vimrc
```

Or from within vim itself:

```
:%s/\r//g
```

On the off-chance you have `\r`s you actually want to keep,

```
:%s/\r$
```

With the implied `//`

Comment: You can also type `<c-v><CR>` (Control-V followed by the enter key) to generate `^M`

Comment: Yes, or `<c-v><c-m>`.